# How to Clear MemoryCache of IIS hosted application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, caching, memorycache

I have a CMS Application in .net 6 mvc, I've published that app on IIS server local. I've implemented cache system using `MemoryCache`.

I have written code to expire all cache when I publish a Content to server. But it is not taking effect until I restart server.

I think cache is not clearing from Server, help me to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can you show the code?